# Creating reusable draw functions in Jetpack Compose Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm drawing multiple rings in a Compose Canvas by using the `drawArc()` function

[image]

Most of values being passed into `drawArc()` are the same apart from `colour`, `sweepAngle` and a radius value for controlling the ring size. I would like to abstract most of the drawArc code into a external, reusable function and just pass in those customizable values so I can keep my Canvas code small and easier to read, but I'm struggling trying to provide the Drawscope exposed by the Canvas composable.

Is it possible to do something along the lines of -

```
Canvas() {
    drawRing(Color.Red, 360f, 200f)
    drawRing(Color.Blue, 180f, 400f) 
}

//ComposeUtils.kt
fun drawRing(color: Color, sweepAngle: Float, arcRadius: Float) {
    
    //Drawscope here?
   
    val canvasWidth = size.width
    val canvasHeight = size.height

    drawArc(
        color = color,
        startAngle = 0f,
        sweepAngle = sweepAngle,
        useCenter = false,
        topLeft = Offset(
           (canvasWidth / 2) - (arcRadius / 2),
            canvasHeight / 2 - (arcRadius / 2)
        ),
        size = Size(arcRadius,
        arcRadius),
        style = Stroke(10.0f))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your function as extensions of `DrawScope`:

```
fun DrawScope.drawRing(style: Style, color: Color, sweepAngle: Float, arcRadius: Float)
```

This way you'll have `DrawScope` bound to `this` inside your function.

Notice that this isn't too different from how the lambda provided by `Canvas` is defined. It's a lambda with receiver:

```
fun Canvas(modifier: Modifier, contentDescription: String, onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit)
```